# AWS DMS partition data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I want to replicate data to S3 using DMS but I also want to partition the data so that I can create a table partitioned table in Athena and query the data cost effectively

Answer (score 0):

You should simply configure AWS DMS S3 target endpoint to use date-based partitioning:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html#CHAP_Target.S3.DatePartitioning

You can achieve that by setting `DatePartitionEnabled` in S3 target endpoint to true. You can configure that in endpoint details, by going to "Endpoint settings" tab, or when using CloudFormation, simply set `DataPartitionEnable`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dms-endpoint-s3settings.html